# Kubuntu not grabbing extra RAM after upgrade to 21.04

Tags: ram, do-release-upgrade

I have:

> Operating System: Ubuntu 21.04 KDE Plasma Version: 5.21.4 KDE
> Frameworks Version: 5.80.0 Qt Version: 5.15.2 Kernel Version:
> 5.11.0-37-generic OS Type: 64-bit Graphics Platform: X11 Processors: 4 × Intel® Pentium® CPU 4415U @ 2.30GHz Memory: 3.6 GiB of RAM Graphics
> Processor: Mesa Intel® HD Graphics 610

I have 8GB of extra RAM in my Lenovo laptop and they were detected and worked before this upgrade.

sudo lshw -C memory

```
description: BIOS
       vendor: LENOVO
       physical id: 0
       version: 4WCN40WW
       date: 04/13/2018
       size: 128KiB
       capacity: 6080KiB
       capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect edd int13floppynec int13floppytoshiba int13floppy360 int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int9keyboard int10video acpi usb biosbootspecification uefi
  *-cache:0
       description: L1 cache
       physical id: 5
       slot: L1 Cache
       size: 128KiB
       capacity: 128KiB
       capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=1
  *-cache:1
       description: L2 cache
       physical id: 6
       slot: L2 Cache
       size: 512KiB
       capacity: 512KiB
       capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=2
  *-cache:2
       description: L3 cache
       physical id: 7
       slot: L3 Cache
       size: 2MiB
       capacity: 2MiB
       capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=3
  *-memory
       description: System Memory
       physical id: 24
       slot: System board or motherboard
       size: 4GiB
     *-bank:0
          description: SODIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 2133 MHz (0.5 ns)
          product: M471A5244CB0-CRC
          vendor: Samsung
          physical id: 0
          serial: 00000000
          slot: ChannelA-DIMM0
          size: 4GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 2133MHz (0.5ns)
     *-bank:1
          description: [empty]
          physical id: 1
          slot: ChannelB-DIMM0
  *-memory UNCLAIMED
       description: Memory controller
       product: Sunrise Point-LP PMC
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.2
       version: 21
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz (30.3ns)
       capabilities: bus_master
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:a1324000-a1327fff
```

sudo dmidecode -t memory

```
# dmidecode 3.3
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 3.0 present.

Handle 0x0024, DMI type 16, 23 bytes
Physical Memory Array
        Location: System Board Or Motherboard
        Use: System Memory
        Error Correction Type: None
        Maximum Capacity: 32 GB
        Error Information Handle: No Error
        Number Of Devices: 2

Handle 0x0025, DMI type 17, 40 bytes
Memory Device
        Array Handle: 0x0024
        Error Information Handle: No Error
        Total Width: 64 bits
        Data Width: 64 bits
        Size: 4 GB
        Form Factor: SODIMM
        Set: None
        Locator: ChannelA-DIMM0
        Bank Locator: BANK 0
        Type: DDR4
        Type Detail: Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered)
        Speed: 2133 MT/s
        Manufacturer: Samsung
        Serial Number: 00000000
        Asset Tag: 9876543210
        Part Number: M471A5244CB0-CRC    
        Rank: 1
        Configured Memory Speed: 2133 MT/s
        Minimum Voltage: 1.5 V
        Maximum Voltage: 1.5 V
        Configured Voltage: 1.2 V

Handle 0x0026, DMI type 17, 40 bytes
Memory Device
        Array Handle: 0x0024
        Error Information Handle: No Error
        Total Width: Unknown
        Data Width: Unknown
        Size: No Module Installed
        Form Factor: Unknown
        Set: None
        Locator: ChannelB-DIMM0
        Bank Locator: BANK 2
        Type: Unknown
        Type Detail: None
        Speed: Unknown
        Manufacturer: Not Specified
        Serial Number: Not Specified
        Asset Tag: Not Specified
        Part Number: Not Specified
        Rank: Unknown
        Configured Memory Speed: Unknown
        Minimum Voltage: Unknown
        Maximum Voltage: Unknown
        Configured Voltage: Unknown
```

sudo swapon --show

```
NAME      TYPE SIZE USED PRIO
/swapfile file  15G 2.8M   -2
```

Comment: Use `sudo journalctl  -b 0`, and page through. Did your system see the extra memory? `swapon` only deals with swap. Use `free` to see RAM.

Comment: Re-seat the SODIMMS in their sockets. One isn't been seen. I'll bet that the BIOS doesn't see it either.

Comment: @heynnema So the software upgrade caused the RAM to unseat itself?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Probably not.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix re-seating the SODIMMS **did** fix the problem :-)

Comment: @heynnema Well what do you **know** :)

Comment: All a sudden Ubuntu does not grab the extra RAM again. I have tried to re-seat them but without luck this time. What to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments...

Re-seat the SODIMMS in their sockets. One isn't been seen. I'll bet that the BIOS doesn't see it either.

**Update #1:**

Re-seating the SODIMMS fixed the problem.